# Why does my script throw an error even if it's successful?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I have made a template batch script that I can tell to carry out a function. I usually use it for pointing to files or locations, in this case, I want it to find and highlight a file and throw a custom error if the target isn't present. Whether the target is present or not, my script throws my error. What am I doing wrong or missing?

---

Here is my script:

```
SET TARGETPATH= "%TARGETPATH%"
IF NOT EXIST= "%TARGETPATH%" GOTO :ERROR
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /select, "%TARGETPATH%"
:END

:ERROR
SET msgboxTitle=%TITLE%
SET msgboxBody=%MESSAGE%
SET tmpmsgbox=%TEMP%\Message.vbs
IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"
ECHO msgbox "%msgboxBody%",0,"%msgboxTitle%">"%tmpmsgbox%"
WSCRIPT "%tmpmsgbox%"

:END
```

I have moved and adjusted he position of line 3 *(the target selector)* to many different positions to prevent the error in a successful target acquisition. I have even set a `:END` after the selector among many other things. How can I get this script to throw the error if, and **only** if the specified target isn't present?

Comment: Check your syntax. To my knowledge the IF uses IF .. == .. so you're missing an =.

Comment: Line 4 should be `goto END`; otherwise, after line 3 you will drop through into the error handling code.

Comment: `NOT EXIST` doesn't require `=` at all, just use ` NOT EXIST "%TARGETPATH%"`

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I combined @AFH's `goto END:` that I forgot to add in combination with @Máté Juhász's code correction. The script functions correctly now. If some one would like to provide the solution an answer, I will accept and upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 2 : IF NOT EXIST should look like this

```
If Not Exist %TARGETPATH% GOTO :ERROR
```

---

And at line 4

```
goto :END
```

---

From [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780553/if-not-exist-cmd-command-not-working)